# Memory leak at allocated/reallocted memory, "5 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost"

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm getting a valgrind error when checking my program for memory leaks.
The error happens somewhere in my cutString function when allocating/reallocating memory, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Am I allocating my memory incorrectly?

Here's the valgrind output:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./cutstring
==7017== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7017== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.           
==7017== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info                                     
==7017== Command: ./cutstring
==7017==
Hell
==7017==
==7017== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7017==     in use at exit: 5 bytes in 1 blocks
==7017==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 1,042 bytes allocated                                           
==7017==
==7017== 5 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1                          
==7017==    at 0x4839D7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:826)
==7017==    by 0x109205: cutString (in cutstring)
==7017==    by 0x109228: main (in cutstring)
==7017==
==7017== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7017==    definitely lost: 5 bytes in 1 blocks
==7017==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7017==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7017==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7017==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7017==
==7017== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7017== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

This is my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *cutString(char *str, char del)
{ 
  char *new_string = (char*) malloc(strlen(str) * sizeof(char) + 1);

  int i = 0;
  while (str[i] != del)
  {
    new_string[i] = str[i];
    i++;
  }

  new_string[i] = '\0';

  new_string = (char*) realloc(new_string, strlen(new_string) + 1);

  return new_string;
  free(new_string);
}

int main()
{
  printf("%s\n", cutString("Hello World!", 'o'));
  return 0;
}
```

I'm guessing that I used realloc incorrectly, but I can't figure out why.
Some help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `free(new_string);` after `return` does nothing. And you have a memory leak because you're not storing the pointer but just feeding it to `printf`

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *new_string = (char*) malloc(strlen(str) * sizeof(char) + 1);` and similar statements.  1) In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  3) regarding the expression: ` sizeof(char)`  this is defined in the C standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expressing and the casting

Comment: regarding: `  return new_string;
  free(new_string);`  The 'return' exits the function, so the call to `free()` will never be executed

Comment: regarding: `new_string =  realloc(new_string, strlen(new_string) + 1);`  Why bother with the `realloc()`   it hurts nothing if a slightly oversized amount of heap memory is allocated

Comment: in the function: `main()`, after the call to `printf()` is the proper place to call `free()`  However, the pointer returned from the function: `cutstring()` is not visible outside the call to `printf()`.  Suggest saving the returned value to a pointer, then passing the pointer to `printf()` and to `free()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cutString` has to allocate memory and return it. Of course (and fortunately), all statements *after* an inconditional `return` aren't reached.

```
  return new_string;
  free(new_string);   // never executed
}
```

Fortunately! because else you'd return unallocated memory: undefined behaviour.

The issue here is that you're passing the returned value to `printf`, but after that call, the pointer is lost. You have to store it to be able to free it, but *only after having printed it*.

```
int main()
{
  char *s = cutString("Hello World!", 'o'));
  printf("%s\n", s);
  free(s);
  return 0;
}
```

In C it's not possible to pipeline a function which allocates memory to `printf` without creating a memory leak. Other languages have garbage collectors or object destructors, but not C.